# what's the difference between pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION and pycurl.WRITEDATA?

Tags: python, pycurl

I just want to know the difference of the following two statements:

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, fp.write)
```

fp is a file descriptor, and fp.write is a function.
Could anybody tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [`WRITEDATA` callback](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEDATA) option, you can control which file the default [`WRITEFUNCTION` callback](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION) writes to.

The function set with the `WRITEFUNCTION` option is the one which is actually called as soon as there is data received that needs to be saved.

Normally, the value you specify to `WRITEDATA` will be passed to the `WRITEFUNCTION` callback, but in [PyCurl, the `WRITEFUNCTION` callback just takes a single string as argument](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/callbacks.html), so there's not much use in using `WRITEDATA` with  `WRITEFUNCTION` together in PyCurl.